# Handling large pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

UPDATED question:

I have a 120000x14000 matrix that is sparse. Then I want to do some matrix algebra:

```
c = np.sum(indM, axis=1).T
w = np.diag(1 / np.array(c)[0]) # Fails with memory error
w = sparse.eye(len(indM), dtype=np.float)/np.array(c)[0] # Fails with memory error
w = np.nan_to_num(w)
u = w @ indM # Fails with 'Object types not supported'
u_avg = np.array(np.sum(u, axis=0) / np.sum(indM, axis=0))[0]
```

So the problem is that the above first fails with memory error when creating a diagonal matrix with non-integers in the diagonal. If I manage to procese, the kernel somehow don't recognize "Objects" as supported types meaning I can't do sparse matrices, I think?

What do you recommend I do?

Comment: @ScottBoston Oops, but that's still a lot of data. 3.6 billion elements :D

Answer (score 2):

Try using numpy's sum. In my experience, it tends to blow other stuff out of the water when it comes to performance.

```
import numpy as np
c = np.sum(indM,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't have enough RAM to handle such a large array. The obvious choice here is to use methods from `scipy.sparse` but you say you've tried that and still encounter a memory problem. Fortunately, there are still a few other options:

1. Change your dataframe to a numpy array (this may reduce memory overhead)
2. You could use `numpy.memmap` to map your array to a location stored in binary *on disk*.
3. At the expense of precision, you could change the `dtype` of any floats from `float64` (the default) to `float32`.
4. If you are loading your data from a .csv file, `pd.read_csv` has an option `chunksize` which allows you to read in your data in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a cloud-based resource like Kaggle. There may be more processing power available there than on your machine.